# jQuery Multi Window Access and Handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, window.open

I'm working on a web application that relies on jQuery quite a bit. I have a select that is structured like:

```
<select id='task_id'>
    <option value=''>Select</option>
    <option value='0001'>First Task</option>
    <option value='0002'>Second Task</option>
    <option value='addnew'>Add New...</option>
</select>
```

And I also have some jQuery that opens a new window when someone selects "Add New...", so they can enter the details on another page.

```
var newTask;
$("select").change(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == "addnew" ){        
       if( newTask )
          newTask.close();
       newTask = window.open( "/projects/add-task", "newTask", "width=990,height=600" );
    } else {
       if(newTask)
          newTask.close();
    }
```

I want to add an event handler from the parent window to the form submit button on the child window, so that when someone submits the form (ie they're done adding), the window will close. What I have is this:

```
    $("form", newTask.document).submit(function(){
       newTask.close();
    });
});
```

Just by itself, it doesn't work, but it doesn't throw any errors. If I open up the Chrome Inspector, and run the following, line by line, it behaves slightly differently:

```
1. var newWin = window.open("/projects/new");

2. $("form", newWin.document).submit(function(){
      newWin.close();
   });
```

I guess my questions are why doesn't it work unless I manually run it line by line through the console, and how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that newtask is defined in the parent window, and i don't think that you can acces it from the child window, so the best solution will be to pre-load your javascript event in the add-task page. the event will be slightly different:

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
    window.close();
});
```

this code snippet should be already included in your add-task page.
I hope this is usefull.

Comment: I'm not trying to access the parent window from the child one, but the other way around. I know I can do it, because I've done it manually with the Inspector, but when I try to do with just a script, it doesn't work. I think it has something to do with the DOM not being loaded yet on the child window.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. It was a problem with the DOM not being totally loaded when I tried to attach the event handler.

```
if(newTask)
   newTask.onload = function(){
     $("input[type=submit]", newTask.document).click(function(){
        newTask.close();
     });
   };
```

Next question is how would I "jQuery-ify" that? I don't like using "el.onload", but I can't seem to make any variation of

```
$(newTask.document).ready();
```

or

```
$(document, newTask).ready();
```

actually work.